# Mod_Rewrite and SuPHP - a php redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have just upgraded from shared hosting to a managed VPS with godaddy. My problem is that my links no longer work.  The link URL is run through Mod_Rewrite.  it rewrites the incoming URL to go to a php script that redirects the links.  This is good for me because it cloaks the link.

For some reason it does not work now.  There are no errors.  The URL just shows in the browser address bar but it is not redirected.   This worked on the shared hosting.

Here are the details of my set up.
CentOS & cPanel
php 5.5
suPHP is the handler being used
AllowOverride ALL is enabled (by default I believe)
RewriteEngine On (in .htaccess)

This is the rule in my .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^take_me_to/([/_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)?$ xx/xx.php?id=$1
```

This is what's in my go.php file

```
    <?php
if ($id == "ID taken from the link URL") {$url =affiliate URL}   

header("Location: $url");
    exit();
?>
```

I do not know if the problem is with the rewrite, or how the script is being run.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, can anyone help with this.  I've spent some time on it and can't think what is going on.

Comment: What happens if you enter one of the desired URLs?

Comment: Hi, the URL sits in the address bar and it is not forwarded.  In the end it was the PHP that was out of date and not working with PHP5 that my new VPS uses.  I asked a developer to check my php code who updated it for me.